# auto generate title of custom post type which concludes id not working

Tags: functions

I create the title of the custom-post-type "produktionsauftrag" automatically. The script in my functions.php works but i cant get the postid at the end of my title.

Filter in my functions.php file:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','update_pa_title',99,2);
function update_pa_title($data, $postarr) {
global $post;
  if ( !is_admin() )
        return $data;

    if ($data['post_type'] == 'produktionsauftrag') {

        $data['post_title'] = 'Produktionsauftrag - ' . $post_id;

        return $data;
    } else {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with title_save_pre

```
add_filter('title_save_pre','auto_generate_post_title');
function auto_generate_post_title($title) {
   global $post;
   if (isset($post->ID)) {
      if (empty($_POST['post_title']) && 'produktionsauftrag' == get_post_type($post->ID)){
         // get the current post ID number
         $id = get_the_ID();
         // add ID number with order strong
         $title = 'produktionsauftrag-'.$id;} }
   return $title; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The filter "wp_insert_post_data" runs before the data is inserted into the database. When you create a new post, the ID is not set yet, it is set by the auto_increment field in the database.

You can use a filter or action later in the process like [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).